pushing a unique_ptr into a vector of variant unique_ptr
I am playing around with C++ and faced this problem.
If I have a variant that looks like this:
using Fruit = variant<Apple, Tomato>
and a vector of unique_ptr of Fruit:
vector<unique_ptr<Fruit>> fruits
How can I move a unique_ptr<Apple> into the fruits vector?
Here is an example piece of code:
#include <variant>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct Apple {};
struct Tomato {};

using Fruit = variant<Apple, Tomato>;

int main() {
    vector<unique_ptr<Fruit>> fruits;
    unique_ptr<Apple> apple = make_unique<Apple>();
    fruits.push_back(unique_ptr<Fruit>(move(apple))); // error here
}

On the call to push_back, I get this error:
No matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'remove_reference_t<unique_ptr<Apple, default_delete<Apple>> &>' (aka 'std::unique_ptr<Apple>') to 'unique_ptr<Fruit>' (aka 'unique_ptr<variant<Apple, Tomato>>')

If I change the line to:
fruits.push_back(unique_ptr<Apple>(move(apple)));

I get this error:
No matching member function for call to 'push_back'

And if I change it to this:
fruits.emplace_back(unique_ptr<Apple>(move(apple)));

no error occurs.
So, is using emplace_back() the right choice here?
Why does this error occur? I am assuming it is because I can't cast a unique_ptr<VariantMemberType> to a unique_ptr<VariantType>?
EDIT:
emplace_back() results in a compile-time error, LSP didn't give errors so I assumed it was valid and forgot to actually compile it.

How are you compiling this code? fruits.emplace_back(unique_ptr<Apple>(move(apple))); I get compiler errors when I try.

@FrançoisAndrieux you're right, fixed the question.

If you want to avoid the copy, you can always declare FruitPtr = variant<unique_ptr<Apple>, unique_ptr<Tomato>> and store a vector of those instead.

Fruit is unrelated to Apple. A Fruit just potentially contains an Apple. There is no way to convert a pointer to Apple to a pointer to Fruit for the same reason you can't convert a pointer to int to a pointer to std::set<int>. The best you can do is make a new Fruit object and move the value pointed to by apple into the new Fruit.
#include <memory>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>


struct Apple {};
struct Tomato {};

using Fruit = std::variant<Apple, Tomato>;

int main() {
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Fruit>> fruits;
    std::unique_ptr<Apple> apple = std::make_unique<Apple>();
    fruits.push_back(std::make_unique<Fruit>(std::move(*apple)));
}

Notice that we now make a new Fruit with std::make_unique and move the value of the object pointed to by apple instead of moving the pointer. It's worth noting that you will now have a moved-from Apple pointed to by apple. If you need its lifetime to end you need to reset the pointer manually.

that makes sense, thanks!

You are storing pointers to Fruit, so you need to construct Fruit objects.  And since Fruit is a variant, you have to assign the desired type of value to each Fruit object, eg:
#include <vector>
#include <variant>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct Apple {};
struct Tomato {};

using Fruit = variant<Apple, Tomato>;

int main() {
    vector<unique_ptr<Fruit>> fruits;

    auto apple = make_unique<Fruit>();
    *apple = Apple{};
    // or: auto apple = make_unique<Fruit>(Apple{});
    // or: auto apple = make_unique<Fruit>(in_place_type<Apple>); 
    fruits.push_back(move(apple));

    auto tomato = make_unique<Fruit>();
    *tomato = Tomato{};
    // or: auto tomato = make_unique<Fruit>(Tomato{});
    // or: auto tomato = make_unique<Fruit>(in_place_type<Tomato>);
    fruits.push_back(move(tomato));
}


That being said, your use of std::variant makes no sense to me. A fruit should not be a choice between an apple or a tomato.  Apple and tomato are types of fruits, so you should be using inheritance instead of variance.
Define Fruit as a base class which Apple and Tomato derive from, then you can store Apple and Tomato pointers in your vector of Fruit pointers, eg:
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct Fruit {
    virtual ~Fruit() = default;
};

struct Apple : Fruit {};
struct Tomato : Fruit {};

int main() {
    vector<unique_ptr<Fruit>> fruits;

    auto apple = make_unique<Apple>();
    fruits.push_back(move(apple));
    // or: fruits.push_back(make_unique<Apple>());

    auto tomato = make_unique<Tomato>();
    fruits.push_back(move(tomato));
    // or: fruits.push_back(make_unique<Tomato>());
}


yeah inheritance seems like the simpler choice in this case, thank you for the answer
